# Как через css сделать высоту и ширину SVG равной тому, что рисуется внутри (use => path)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

у меня высота и ширина тега svg почему то 150h * 300w но иконка `19*19`
Как через css сделать что-то типа этого:

```
svg{
  width: inner-content-width;
  height: inner-content-height;
}
```

я могу конечно для svg задать так но это не целесообразно у меня размеры svg разные

```
svg{
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
}
```

пример svg

```
<svg id="search" width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19" fill="none" 

xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M19 17L13.846 11.846C14.7988 10.3979 15.1805 8.64774 14.917 6.93442C14.6536 5.22111 13.7638 3.66648 12.4199 2.57154C11.076 1.47659 9.37369 0.919227 7.64247 1.00735C5.91125 1.09547 4.27431 1.82281 3.04857 3.04855C1.82283 4.27429 1.09549 5.91123 1.00737 7.64245C0.91925 9.37366 1.47662 11.076 2.57156 12.4199C3.6665 13.7637 5.22113 14.6535 6.93445 14.917C8.64777 15.1804 10.3979 14.7988 11.846 13.846L17 19L19 17ZM3 7.99998C3 5.24298 5.243 2.99998 8 2.99998C10.757 2.99998 13 5.24298 13 7.99998C13 10.757 10.757 13 8 13C5.243 13 3 10.757 3 7.99998Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как я успел узнать через css никак нельзя задать размер равный ребенку
вот мое решение

```
import React from 'react'
import useResizeObserver from "use-resize-observer";

interface SvgCreatorProps{
    clsName:string,
    svgHref:string
}

export const SvgCreator:React.FC<SvgCreatorProps> = ({clsName,svgHref}) => {
    const { ref, width = 1, height = 1 } = useResizeObserver<any>();
    return (
        <svg width={width} height={height} className={clsName}>
                <use ref={ref} href={svgHref} />
        </svg>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> у меня высота и ширина тега svg почему то 150h * 300w но иконка 19*19

Так происходит, когда не задан `viewBox` и размеры SVG   браузер не знает и выводит  по умолчанию для SVG:

**ширина 300px, высота 150px.**

Проверьте свою вёрстку, здесь в иконке указан `viewBox`, в вашем приложении видимо не указан.

Ниже пример, где у вашей иконки есть `viewBox= 0 0 19 19` Она обернута div, у которого `width="19px" height="19px"`  В этом случае иконка будет иметь те же размеры, что и родительский блок.

Вы можете использовать её многократно, при этом перекрашивать, масштабировать, позиционировать иконку.

**Обратите внимание на правило CSS**

```
path {
fill:inherit;
}
```

Это сделано, чтобы была возможность стилизации, после использования тега `<use>`

```html
<style>
.wrapper {
width:19px;
height:19px;
}
path {
fill:inherit;
}
</style>
<div>
<div class="wrapper">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            viewBox="0 0 19 19">  
    <symbol id="search">
    <path fill="black" d="M19 17L13.846 11.846C14.7988 10.3979 15.1805 8.64774 14.917 6.93442C14.6536 5.22111 13.7638 3.66648 12.4199 2.57154C11.076 1.47659 9.37369 0.919227 7.64247 1.00735C5.91125 1.09547 4.27431 1.82281 3.04857 3.04855C1.82283 4.27429 1.09549 5.91123 1.00737 7.64245C0.91925 9.37366 1.47662 11.076 2.57156 12.4199C3.6665 13.7637 5.22113 14.6535 6.93445 14.917C8.64777 15.1804 10.3979 14.7988 11.846 13.846L17 19L19 17ZM3 7.99998C3 5.24298 5.243 2.99998 8 2.99998C10.757 2.99998 13 5.24298 13 7.99998C13 10.757 10.757 13 8 13C5.243 13 3 10.757 3 7.99998Z" />    
    </symbol>   
      
</svg>
</div> 
  <!-- 1-ая иконка -->
<div class="wrapper"> 
   <svg> 
     <use href="#search" />
   </svg>
</div> 
  <!-- 2-ая иконка -->
<div class="wrapper"> 
   <svg> 
     <use href="#search" fill="red" x="20"/>
   </svg>
</div>
  <!-- 3-ая иконка -->
<div class="wrapper"> 
   <svg> 
     <use href="#search" fill="green" x="40" transform="scale(1.5)" />
   </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

Как комментирует **@Armen**

> вроде работает но создает другие проблемы wrapper не считается с
> размерами svg... как итог svg наежает на другой блок

Добавьте `viewBox` в `<svg>.. </svg>`, которые вторично вызывают иконки

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
   <svg viewBox="0 0 19 19"> 
     <use href="#search" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

```css
<style>
.container {
 }
.wrapper {
width:19px;
height:19px;
}
path {
fill:inherit;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div>
<div class="wrapper">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            viewBox="0 0 19 19">  
    <symbol id="search">
    <path fill="black" d="M19 17L13.846 11.846C14.7988 10.3979 15.1805 8.64774 14.917 6.93442C14.6536 5.22111 13.7638 3.66648 12.4199 2.57154C11.076 1.47659 9.37369 0.919227 7.64247 1.00735C5.91125 1.09547 4.27431 1.82281 3.04857 3.04855C1.82283 4.27429 1.09549 5.91123 1.00737 7.64245C0.91925 9.37366 1.47662 11.076 2.57156 12.4199C3.6665 13.7637 5.22113 14.6535 6.93445 14.917C8.64777 15.1804 10.3979 14.7988 11.846 13.846L17 19L19 17ZM3 7.99998C3 5.24298 5.243 2.99998 8 2.99998C10.757 2.99998 13 5.24298 13 7.99998C13 10.757 10.757 13 8 13C5.243 13 3 10.757 3 7.99998Z" />    
    </symbol>   
      
</svg>
</div> 
  <!-- 1-ая иконка -->
<div class="wrapper"> 
   <svg viewBox="0 0 19 19"> 
     <use href="#search" />
   </svg>
</div> 
  <!-- 2-ая иконка -->
<div class="wrapper"> 
   <svg viewBox="0 0 19 19"> 
     <use href="#search" fill="red" />
   </svg>
</div>
  <!-- 3-ая иконка -->
<div class="wrapper"> 
   <svg viewBox="0 0 19 19"> 
     <use href="#search" fill="green"/>
   </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Alexandr__TT вроде работает но создает другие проблемы wrapper не считается с размерами svg... как итог svg наежает на другой блок

Comment: спасибо огромное за кучу новой инфы но это не как не решает проблему... а что если другой svg имеет не 19*19 a 45*45